# Rest web sercive path Not Found

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-boot

Try to hit my web service through rest client http://localhost:8080/gurukul/userList but it shows error 'Not Found'.

```
{
"timestamp": 1462078050576
"status": 404
"error": "Not Found"
"message": "No message available"
"path": "/gurukul/userList"
}
```

below is My controller in which I add path by RequestMapping but still not found the path after spring-boot

```
package controller;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import bean.UserList;
    import common.Status;
    import constants.Constants;
    import constants.Messages;
    import dao.UserListDAO;

    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Controller
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("gurukul")
    public class GurukulController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/userList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, Object> getUsersList() {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

            UserListDAO userListDAO = (UserListDAO) context.getBean("userListDAO");
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<UserList> listResult = userListDAO.getUsers();
            if (listResult != null) {
                resultMap.put(Constants.RESULT, listResult);
                resultMap.put(Constants.STATUS, Status.SUCCESS);
            } else {
                resultMap.put(Constants.RESULT, Messages.UNABLE_TO_GET_USERS_LIST);
                resultMap.put(Constants.STATUS, Status.FAILURE);
            }
            return resultMap;
        }

    }

    enter code here
```

Comment: Are you using an embedded container or deploying to a standalone container? If it's the former, what does your main class look like and what package is it in? If it's the latter, have you extended `SpringBootServletInitializer`? In either case, what context path are you using? A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very useful here

Answer (score 0):

your URL should have been http://localhost:8080/context root/Controller class Path/serivice method path

Use http://localhost:8080/context root path/gurukul/userList

Comment: Its not about the path, because if I put controller in the package where my MainAppliction program is present, then after running spring-boot I can hit my web service. but if I put MyController it into controller package it could not find the path